# Show more than one figure one by one in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have 20 figures to display one after another like slide show. Can I do it using Imshow in Matlab? Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MOVIE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/movie.html) to display plots/images one after the other. For this, you create the figures, capture them via [GETFRAME](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getframe.html), and then you can call `movie`. See this example from the help for `getframe`

```
Z = peaks; surf(Z)
axis tight
set(gca,'NextPlot','replacechildren');
for j = 1:20
    surf(sin(2*pi*j/20)*Z,Z)
    F(j) = getframe;
end
movie(F,20) % Play the movie twenty times
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple options:

- Open a figure for each plot
- Open and close a figure for each plot
- Reuse one figure

**Open a figure for each plot**

```
for i=1:20
  h = figure;
  %plot here
  pause
end
```

**Open and close a figure for each plot**

```
for i=1:20
  h = figure;
  %plot 
  pause
  close gcf
end
```

**Reuse one figure**

```
h=figure
for i=1:20
    clf(h);
    %plot
    pause
end
```

OR depending on what you are plotting, you can use the [refreshdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/refreshdata.html) method.

If you use @Jonas' method, **and** if you have dual monitors, you have to force the figure to the main monitor for getframe to actually work, [as per](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-21DVDX/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-21DVDX). You can do this via:

```
ff=figure;
movegui(ff)
```